# How $N(2\zeta^{2n})=2^{p-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, normed-spaces, roots-of-unity

Let, $\zeta$ be the $p$ th root of unity and  $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$ be the number ring generated by $\zeta$, and $N$ is the norm function.

Why or how $N(2\zeta^{2n})=2^{p-1}$?

The source of the problem is -

[image]

Comment: $2\in\mathbb Q$, so $N(2)=2^{p-1}$, because $[\mathbb Q[\zeta]:\mathbb Q]=p-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks could u plz name/state the theorem or anything that I can use to search to know the theorem in detail?

Comment: Your $\zeta$ is the same as the source's $\xi$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The norm is a homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm#Group_homomorphism) from the multiplicative group $\mathbb Q[\zeta]^\ast$ to $\mathbb Q^\ast$,

so $N(2\zeta^{2n})=N(2)N(\zeta^{2n}),$ and $N(2)=2^{p-1}$ and $N(\zeta^{2n})=1$.

$[\mathbb Q[\zeta]:\mathbb Q]=p-1$, and $N(2)$ is the product of the $p-1$ conjugates of $2$, which are all $2$,

since $2$ is in the base field.  $\zeta^n$ is a unit, so its norm is $\pm1$, so $N(\zeta^{2n})=1.$

Comment: Thanks I got it, my understanding on norm function was incomplete, anyway could you comment on how $\xi^nu_{p-1} \in \mathbb{R}$ in the last line of the attached image? Is there a simple derivation like my original question?

Here, $u$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\xi]$. In this case we define $u_s := g(ξ^s)$ and it is a Galois conjugate of $u$, $\xi$ is the root of unity.

Comment: $\xi^nu_{p-1}\in\mathbb R$ because it's congruent to its complex conjugate $\pmod{(1-\xi)}$